# How do I get a confusion matrix to output a consistently shaped array (2x2) for a binary classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm looping and creating tn, fp, fn, tp for each dataset I have and for some datasets there's only 0's and I predict only 0's so I only return a 1x1 array for tp but I still want a 2x2 matrix returned so I don't get `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)` during the following bit of python:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(metrics_data[label_column],metrics_data[scored_column]).ravel()
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the labels parameter to your confusion matrix command, eg

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(
    metrics_data[label_column],
    metrics_data[scored_column], 
    labels=[0, 1]).ravel()
```

From [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) for `sklearn.metrics.confustion_matrix`, `labels` is an array-like of shape (n_classes) and defined as:

> List of labels to index the matrix. This may be used to reorder or select a subset of labels. If None is given, those that appear at least once in y_true or y_pred are used in sorted order.

Since you have provided None, `confuision_matrix` is defaulting to only the values it has actually seen in your data.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

> ```
> sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, *, labels=None, sample_weight=None, normalize=None)[source]
> Compute confusion matrix to evaluate the accuracy of a classification.
>
> By definition a confusion matrix  is such that  is equal to the number of observations known to be in group  and predicted to be in
> group .
>
> Thus in binary classification, the count of true negatives is , false negatives is , true positives is  and false positives is .
>
> Read more in the User Guide.
>
> Parameters
> y_truearray-like of shape (n_samples,)
> Ground truth (correct) target values.
>
> y_predarray-like of shape (n_samples,)
> Estimated targets as returned by a classifier.
>
> labelsarray-like of shape (n_classes), default=None
> List of labels to index the matrix. This may be used to reorder or select a subset of labels. If None is given, those that appear at
> least once in y_true or y_pred are used in sorted order.
> ```

you can use the `labels` argument to enforce equal size, regardless of input predictions:

```
confusion_matrix(true, pred, labels=[1,2,3])
```